# How to appreciate Riemannian geometry

Tags: geometry, differential-geometry, soft-question, riemannian-geometry, motivation

I'm currently following an introduction to Riemannian geometry i.e. connections, curvature and isometric immersions (the Gauss, Codazi and Ricci equations).

I find the introduction to Riemannian geometry interesting, but whenever I look at some theorems beyond the introductory topics they seem quite artificial and not intuitive. Also I can't see why they are interesting for us? 
 
There are many examples, one of them is Schur's lemma which goes as follows:

> Let $M$ be a Riemannian manifold of dimension $n \geq 3$. Suppose that for every plane $\pi$ in $T_pM$, $K(\pi)$ (the sectional curvature) has the same value $c(p)$. Then $c(p)$ is a constant function.

First the theorem only works in $n\geq 3$, but my main problem is that my intuition lives in surfaces in $\mathbb{R}^3$ where there is only one plane $\pi $ in  $T_pM$. Hence what is the intuition behind this lemma? How can one see the beauty of such theorems? 
 
This is however unfortunate since the theory of Riemannian geometry is a popular branch of mathematics which implies many people are interested in it (and probably see the beauty of such theorems and problems). The purpose of my question is to get some intuition or feeling for it so I can appreciate such theorems.

**EDIT 1:** The very general question, has more concrete subquestions:

1. Why are we interested in the relation between curvature and the shape of manifolds, what is the importance of this?
2. How does one intuitively see which relations (in 1)) one can expect and which not? (for example if the sectional curvatures are $\leq 0$ then for what properties of $M$ can one hope for?)
3. Some theorems hold only in specific higher dimensions, for example Schur's lemma above. How does a mathematician find such theorems and proofs?

**EDIT 2:** As suggested in a comment, maybe these questions can be answered by giving interesting examples of the uses of Riemannian geometry.

Comment: I can see what you're driving at but the question seems too vague/broad at present. Are you sure you can't narrow it down to one or two specific results that you want intuition on, instead of an entire subfield?

Comment: Remark: Schur's Lemma might be thought of as a generalization of the following result for surfaces in $\Bbb R^3$: If every point is an umbilic point (both principal curvatures the same), then the surface has constant curvature.

Comment: Thanks, I can see how this relates to Schur's lemma. PS: I just realized that I've read your course notes in my differential geometry class in the past :p

Comment: [_The Shape of Space_](http://www.maa.org/press/maa-reviews/the-shape-of-space) by [Jeffrey Weeks](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jeffrey_Weeks_%28mathematician%29) is likely to be of interest to you.

Comment: Incidentally, the reason I haven't tried to post a systematic answer to your (good!) question is it's still "too broad", i.e., seems to ask for a survey article on Riemannian geometry, maybe not a good fit for the format of Math.SE. Dick Palais' [3D-XplorMath](http://3d-xplormath.org/) and the accompanying [Virtual Math Museum](http://virtualmathmuseum.org/3dxmTovmmTransition.html) may be of interest to you, as well as Jan Koenderink's _Solid Shape_ and Marcel Berger's _A Panoramic View of Riemannian Geometry_. (Each book is about 1000 pages.)

Comment: Although the last book seems to explain things well, it contains indeed many pages. I'd like to read more of it but my exams are coming soon and I can't find the time to read the book thoroughly.

Secondly, thanks for the interest you put into my question but I can't really see how to narrow my question, I'm looking for an explanation why things are done. For example if one would ask for the uses of elementary real analysis I would give examples about compactness, sequences and continuity to give some intuition into the matter. I'm looking for some analog explanation.

Comment: I just came across Schur's lemma here. I think it follows from the differential Bianchi identity, right?

Comment: Regarding DG, I think it is a beautiful subject, with links to Lie groups in various ways, contains local-to-global kind of results, and various comparison results, with links to Analysis and Physics, and in the more advanced areas, links to Number Theory. What more can one want?

Comment: Yes you're right about Schur's lemma. The origin of my question lies maybe in the fact that I've only seen the basics of differential geometry. Like analysis or algebra things become more beautiful the more you get familiar with it. Does the same hold for geometry from your experience?

Comment: I had a different experience. I started getting interested in the beginning due to its connection with GR, then I started  really liking it after reading some work by Chern and also some books by Do Carmo. I ended up doing my PhD in DG too. I guess I liked it from the start.

Comment: I think the Ricci tensor permits to discover if there are extra dimension if it is non vanishing but I'm not sure about that, maybe somebody could indicate more.

Comment: In fact this is not true since Ricci tensor vanishes for the metric of a sphere. In fact there is need for extradimension simply if the nonlinear differential equation that should give the metric have no global solution in the same number of dimension.(but since it is nonlinear Pde there is no general results)

Answer (score 9):

In the spirit of answering a small piece of your large question with a visual image (and noting the meta aspect of gradually covering the complicated manifold of Riemannian geometry with local patches of conceptual coordinates), here's the prototypical non-trivial example of parallel transport, illustrating holonomy (parallel transport around a closed loop is not the identity map on the tangent space) and curvature (the holonomy around a geodesic triangle in a surface is the integral of the curvature over the triangle's interior):

[image: Parallel transport around a spherical triangle]

Answer (score 6):

The first book you should look at is Vladimir Arnold's *Mathematical Methods of Classical Mechanics* where he has a nice introductory discussion of differential geometry and curvature.

The lemma you cited does not have far-reaching consequences and you shouldn't be focusing on it.  One direction of research that is quite popular is the relation between curvature and topology.  It became clear relatively recently (in the 1980s) that positive sectional curvature imposes extremely stringent conditions on the manifold; e.g., one gets a universal upper bound on the sum of all Betti numbers of the manifold by a result of Gromov.  In negative curvature, on the contrary, there is a great wealth of examples, related also to the popular field of Cannon-Gromov-hyperbolic groups.  In general, to get motivated I would suggest looking up work by Gromov. You may not follow all the details (if the details are there :-) but you are likely to be inspired.

Comment: Thank you very much for your references, they certainly seem interesting and motivate Riemannian geometry.

Answer (score 5):

Perhaps this will help,
as it is quite intuitive:
"[Surface in 3D that realizes all pairs of principal curvatures](https://mathoverflow.net/q/136497/6094)":
*angel's curl* surface:

---

[image]

---

Comment: Thanks, could you explain why this relates to my questions? I don't see the link.

Comment: @abcdef: I was trying to illustrate the intuition behind "the relation between curvature and the shape of manifolds," your number 1. Sorry if I misunderstood your question.

Comment: Oh, it is indeed an interesting example.

Comment: You want to see interesting uses of riemannian geometrt?

Comment: That would probably also help a lot! I'll edit my question a bit.

Comment: The ... or let us  say the angel is in the connecting details and after going through it you may wonder how not to appreciate it.