# How can tangent vectors on a curved surface be uniquely combined?

Tags: differential-geometry

Let *C* be a curved surface and let *P* and *Q* be two points on *C* such that $P\neq Q$. Define four unique smooth curves, $γ_{1}(t)$, $γ_{2}(t)$, $γ_{3}(t)$ and $γ_{4}(t)$ on *C*, each curve joining *P* to *Q* along a different path. Let $T_{P}C$ be the tangent plane at *P* and let $v$ be a tangent vector $v\in T_{P}C$. Now, parallel transport $v$ along each curve from *P* to *Q* and let the resulting vectors be denoted $v_{γ_{1}}^{∥v}$, $v_{γ_{2}}^{∥v}$, $v_{γ_{3}}^{∥v}$, and $v_{γ_{4}}^{∥v}$. Since parallel transport is path dependent is it true that $v_{γ_{1}}^{∥v}=v_{γ_{2}}^{∥v}=v_{γ_{3}}^{∥v}=v_{γ_{4}}^{∥v}$, or equivalently, if $u=v_{γ_{1}}^{∥v}$+$v_{γ_{2}}^{∥v}$ and $w=v_{γ_{3}}^{∥v}$+$v_{γ_{4}}^{∥v}$, then $u=w$? If so, how can this be proven? If not, then can we conclude that there is no unique way to combine (add, subtract) vectors on a curved surface? In other words, how can vectors be uniquely combined on a curved surface?

[image]

In this image, tangent vectors at points $f_1,f_2,f_3$ and $f_4$ are parallel transported to a common point $P$ according to: $f_1 \rightarrow P, f_2 \rightarrow P, f_3 \rightarrow P$, and $f_4 \rightarrow P$ along the indicated counterclockwise paths (e.g along parallels and meridians). If the parallel transported vectors are then combined at $P$ (e.g. added), does the resulting vector have meaning in some way?

Comment: This is false. The vector space structure of a tangent space to a manifold has nothing to do at all with parallel transport.

Comment: Thank you very much. Granted, my description may be ill-posed. However, I'm still seeking an answer to the question on parallel transport: If parallel transport on a curved surface is path dependent, can tangent vectors be uniquely combined or compared on that surface?

Comment: What tangent vectors do you want to compare? Tangent vectors based at the same point? At different points?

Comment: Thanks for responding. I don't think I can explain it any better than my original post. But I will try to reword it here.

Comment: Each tangent space to a surface (or manifold) is a vector space, but in general there is no way to add or compare tangent vectors based at different points. (There are exceptions, e.g., if the manifold is equipped with a metric of trivial holonomy so that parallel transport is path-independent, or if any two points are joined by a _unique_ minimizing geodesic, so there is a distinguished path for parallel transport.)

Comment: Thank you very much for this answer. This being the case, it begs the question of what is the purpose of parallel transport? In this reference, ===, the author says:

Comment: In this reference, [Parallel transport on a manifold](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/235909779_Parallel_transport_on_a_manifold), the author says "_That is why we need a general definition of parallel transport, that allows
us to compare different vectors at different points and gives us a prescription on
how to move a vector around a manifold without really altering the vector._ Statements like this are confusing me. Can we or can we not uniquely compare/combine vectors on a curved surface?

Answer (score 1):

> In this reference, [Parallel transport on a manifold](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/235909779_Parallel_transport_on_a_manifold), the author says *"That is why we need a general definition of parallel transport, that allows us to compare different vectors at different points and gives us a prescription on how to move a vector around a manifold without really altering the vector."* Statements like this are confusing me. Can we or can we not uniquely compare/combine vectors on a curved surface?

tl; dr: *No, we cannot.*

---

On a curved Riemannian manifold there is a natural concept of parallel transport *along a piecewise-smooth path* that allows tangent vectors to be "moved along the path," and therefore compared at different points of the path *in a path-dependent sense*.

Further, there are geometrically-special situations where parallel transport is (arguably) unique, e.g.:

- If the manifold is equipped with a metric of trivial holonomy so that parallel transport is path-independent, such as a Euclidean space, or a flat cylinder or torus;
- If any two points are joined by a unique minimizing geodesic, so there is a distinguished path for parallel transport.

Generally, however, there is no natural way to add or compare tangent vectors based at different points. I would not say parallel transport is performed "without really altering the vector." This [animation loop](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2277852/how-to-appreciate-riemannian-geometry) shows why:

[image: Parallel transport around a spherical triangle]

Comment: _Generally, however, there is no natural way to add or compare tangent vectors based at different points_.

Comment: Thank you very much for this answer, it helps a lot. I get that there is no natural way to add or compare tangent vectors based at different points. But, if I parallel transport tangent vectors to a common point and then combine them (e.g. add them), does the result have any meaning? From your answer and others, the result would be meaningless because of the path dependence of parallel transport. That is, if I move the vectors to the same common point along different paths than in the first case, and combine the vectors, I will get a different result. Is this a reasonable conclusion?

Comment: Yes, that's right. Particularly, since it seems you're interested in geography, an arbitrary unit tangent vector to a round sphere at a point p can be parallel transported to any other unit vector based at the same point.

Comment: Thank you for walking me through this. Your explanations have helped. I will endeavor to parallel transport tangent vectors along geodesics in the geodetic applications I am working on.

Comment: On further thought, what _is_ true, and could explain the author's quote, is that parallel transport along a single great circle does allow us to compare tangent vectors at different points  _of that circle_. That's because parallel transport around a great circle is the identity. (Ambiguity arises only if you need to parallel transport along different great circles to compare your tangent vectors, e.g., because you have three points not lying on a great circle.)

Comment: In light of your last comment, I've added a diagram and some additional information to my original post, which better illustrates my question. Perhaps this added information may evoke some new thoughts? (Sorry, I don't know how to add new information sequentially after the comments.)

Comment: With the modifications, the answer is more definitely _no_: If we allow parallel transport over multiple great circles, or over a single meridian, we can rotate vectors by parallel transport as in the animation loop.

Comment: Once again, thanks for your interest in my question and definitive answers. Your responses and others (e.g. the author of the reference I quoted above) confirm that I need to abandon this approach and perform parallel transport along geodesics. By the way, can you recommend any references that address parallel transport of tangent vectors along geodesics on an ellipsoid of revolution?

Comment: Geodesics on surfaces of rotation generally have to be studied numerically rather than analytically. On the bright side, this is a standard topic in introductory books, such as [Ted Shifrin's Open Math Notes](https://www.ams.org/open-math-notes/omn-view-listing?listingId=110755). The search term is _Clairaut metrics_ or the _Clairaut relations_.