# Angle between vector and parallel transport along closed curve on $S^2$

Tags: differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry

I'm trying to solve problem 4.4.15 of Do Carmo's differential geometry but I am having difficulties proving this.
The problem goes as follows:

> Let $p$ be a pole of a unit sphere and $q$, $r$ be two points on the equator in a way that the meridians $pq$ and $pr$ make an angle $\theta$ at $p$. Consider a unit vector $v$ tangent to the meridian $pq$ at $p$ and take the parallel transport of $v$ along the curve of the meridian $pq$, the parallel $qr$ and the meridian $rp$.
> [image]
> Determine the angle of the final position of $v$ with $v$.

My guess is that the angle is $\theta$, since if we take another unit vector $w$ tangent to the meridian $pr$ at $p$, the angle between $v$ and $w$ will be $\theta$. Taking the parallel transport of $w$ until we reach the point $r$ and $v$ until we get to $q$ and then taking the parallel vector field $F_1$ of $w$ at $r$ and $F_2$ of $v$ at $q$ along the meridian would imply that the angle between $F_1$ and $F_2$ is constant. But I'm not sure about this.

Any help is gladly appreciated.

Comment: Are you using the fact that $q$ and $r$ lie on the equator? Make this explicit.

Comment: Not an answer, exactly, but the animation [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2277852/how-to-appreciate-riemannian-geometry) may help.

Answer (score 2):

Your guess is correct, but I am not sure I understand your explanation. If I understand correctly, the vectors $F_1$ and $F_2$ are tangents as $r$ and $q$, respectively. But then, to compare them you should make an additional parallel transport.

A quick way to see what the final angle will be is to appeal to the following fact: parallel trasport along geodesics preserves the angle between the vector and the speed of the geodesic.

Can you guess what happens if the transport is done along a path that instead of being meridian-equator-meridian is meridian-parallel-meridian, for a different parallel? Will the angle be larger or smaller? How does it change with the choice of parallel?